# Drupal 7 field widget - allowed values list

Tags: 7, entities

I need to have a select widget but with custom allowed values per user. Since in D7 I cannot use php code, I was wondering if there is some kind of hook I could use to achieve that functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be [hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta = 0)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7).

The example code for the hook, reported in the documentation is the following one.

```
function hook_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  $element += array(
    '#type' => $instance['widget']['type'], 
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta] : '',
  );
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think hook_field_widget_form_alter() is more what I'm looking for. I'll try it sometimes this week

Comment: true .. just copied it from a module ;)